# How to generate constant row and column sum matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-matrices

How can we randomly generate matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}_{\geq 0}$ that satisfies

$A 1_n = m1$ and $A^T 1_m = n1$.

Comment: You should specify the distribution of the randomly generated matrices. I think that you mean equidistributed in some sense.

Comment: This is generalization to the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73805/sampling-from-the-birkhoff-polytope, which is open.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is what you want, but here are two differnet ways:

1. In the case $m=n$: Generate a bunch of random permutation matrices $A_i$ and take a random linear combination $\sum_i \alpha_i A_i$ with $\sum \alpha_i=n$ and $\alpha_i\geq 0$.
2. Generate a random $m\times n$ matrix and use the Sinkhorn scaling algorithm the equalize row and column sums to the desired values.

Comment: With $\alpha_i\ge0$.

Comment: This is not going to be uniform.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson!

Comment: @AmritanshuPrasad Sure - but there was no indication of any distribution given and my constructions are for sure random (I have no idea what kind of distribution then give…).

Comment: The other answer by Brenday McKay is quite relevant and related to my first point: You want to sample from a generalized Birkhoff polytope: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Generalisations

Comment: @Dirk It was not an objection, but a comment. IMHO the question is defective. It is meaningless to talk about randomness when there is no specified distribution.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of generating a random point in a polytope. There is some work on that general problem, but I don't know if it would be practical for your special case.  For example:

Rubin, [Generating random points in a polytope](https://doi.org/10.1080/03610918408812382), Communications in Statistics - Simulation and Computation, 13 (1984) 375-396.

Probably searching forward and backwards from that will uncover other relevant articles.